# javascript not working in wordpress text widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am running a contest on my workpress blog and placed some javascript code in the text widget area. After inserting the code and refreshing my blog, the page reloads with only the javascript output ad nothing else. My blog does not appear. The code is below. I have used several plugins that supposedly allow javascript/php/jquery in widgets, but none work. FIY, I know very little javascript, and the code below is something I found on this site.

```
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = "Benny & Lily";
myArray[1] = "Minnie and Mack";
myArray[2] = "Daisy";
myArray[3] = "Casey the Boxer";
myArray[4] = "GizmoGeodog";
myArray[5] = "Sam";
myArray[6] = "Max's Mom";
var len = myArray.length;
var chosen = [];
for(var i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    var randy = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
    chosen[i] = myArray[randy];
    for(k = 0; k <= i - 1; k++) {
        if(chosen[k] == chosen[i]) {
            i--; // duplicate found so decrement i
        }
    }
}
document.write(chosen);
```

Comment: What type of contest are you running? Maybe there's a plugin that does what you need it to?

Comment: I tested this briefly and it seems to work fine for me on a default WordPress 3.5.1 site with no plugins, simply by placing the code in a text widget as described. If you have plugins which modify the behavior of scripts in widgets, you might try disabling them, as they could be preventing the script from functioning.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of testing, I realized that my theme was causing the problem. I added a new wordpress installation to my local server and uploaded my current theme in addition to a few other themes (they are all from Elegent Themes). The problem only happened with my theme. Thanks for the help @metadept and @djthoms.